# PHP - Searching strings from a certain format

Tags: php

I've seen other examples using regex however I'm a little bit troubled trying to format mine correctly, I'll have a list of numbers like this:

```
1.0.0.1ACS
1.0.0.2ADS
1.0.1.8AAB
```

However I only want to have the actual 4 numbers but the numbers could turn into multiple digits per line for example 122.222.222.222 (up to 3) how would I go about using PHP to do this? I presume I would have to put them all into a array first then for each in array, then I am confused on how to remove the extra letters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: based on your example, what is the expected result you're looking for?

Comment: Perhaps another array which will output 1.0.0.1 only, rather than 1.0.0.1ACS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yours Code is:

```
<?php
$input = <<<TEST
1.0.0.1ACS
1.0.0.2ADS
1.0.1.8AAB
TEST;
if (!preg_match_all("#(\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})+#", $input, $matches))
    print("NOT FOUND!");
else 
    var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation of *how* and *why* this solves the problem [would really help](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect!

Comment: Paul, if u place script on older php, u can get error. If u get error, try change from `, $matches` to `, &$matches`